# In Ruby, can I check if a string contains a letter without using regular expressions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, include

I'm using Rails 5.  I want to know if a varaible (which you can assume is a String) contains at least one letter (upper case or lower case).  However, I don't want to use regular expressions (I've noticed if the encoding is not UTF-8, regular expressiosn tend to crash).  So I'm wondering how I can check if a string hast at least one letter.

THis doesn't work

```
input.downcase.include?("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
```

Comment: Do you have a concrete example where regex fails for non-UTF8 string?

Comment: Is “ö” a letter? Is “ç” a letter? Is “я” a letter?

Comment: @mudasobwa : it doesn't seem so, Natalia provided a String of acceptable chars.

Comment: Natalia, when non-ASCII characters may be present you can use `str =~ /[[:alpha:]]/` or `str =~ /\p{Alpha}/`.  Search [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html) for "POSIX" and "Character Properties".

Comment: Most likely they are getting `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII` which is a really annoying behavior of regexp in Ruby.

Comment: Or possibly `in 'count': invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 (ArgumentError)`

Comment: Oh bummer, why is Ruby string encoding annoying like that?

Comment: **Encoding** is annoying.

Comment: I know this is not quite what you asked, but the question smells like an AX problem to me.... Could you not just use `String#present?`? `"   ".present? # => false` `"hello".present? # => true`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this

```
str.count("a-zA-Z") > 0
```

The `count` [function](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-count) accepts character sets as argument.

This might still fail with `ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` though. If your input is invalid there is likely no way around fixing the encoding.

*NB, this scans the entire string, but so does `downcase`. For a performance benchmark see Eric's answer, performance varies a lot between worst case and best case scenario. As always though, readability comes before premature optimization.*

Comment: Good catch, fixed!

Comment: It does have the drawback of counting all the letters in a possibly huge string, just to check if there's at least 1.

Comment: Fair enough, let me add a note—both early break and full scan have "exactly the same complexity" though, just saying :)

Comment: Not if you take into account average and worst-case complexity. Your solution does have the advantage of having worst-case as average ;).

Comment: So does using `downcase` as in the other solutions. That scans the entire string to create a copy and even allocate memory for another string.

Comment: Shoot. You got me :D

Comment: "This is the fastest way" {{Citation needed}}

Comment: An `O(n)` native loop is faster than `O(n)` method lookups and method calls. Creating an execution context for a method call is expensive.

Comment: I had a good laugh testing performances of our methods. Mine can be 3000x faster in a good case scenario, but also 300x slower with a worst case.

Answer (score 3):

## Code

You could use :

```
lowercase = ('a'..'z')
uppercase = ('A'..'Z')
input.each_char.any?{ |char| lowercase.cover?(char) || uppercase.cover?(char) }
```

It uses [Range#cover?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html#method-i-cover-3F), which is faster than [Range#include?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Range.html#method-i-include-3F) because it just checks that `char >= 'a'` and `char <= 'z'`.

## Performance

With a worst-case scenario (huge String without letters `"1#+~?5()=[" * 10_000` ) :

```
Running each test 8 times. Test will take about 9 seconds.
_akuhn is faster than _mudasobwa by 2.0x ± 0.01
_mudasobwa is faster than _cary by 14x ± 0.1
_cary is faster than _eric_duminil by 10.5x ± 0.1
```

With the tail of an mp3 file (600kb) :

```
Running each test 2048 times. Test will take about 7 minutes.
_cary is faster than _eric_duminil by 12x ± 1.0
_eric_duminil is faster than _mudasobwa by 430x ± 10.0
_mudasobwa is faster than _akuhn by 3x ± 0.1
```

It's interesting to see the results vary so much.

Comment: `('a'..'z')` will create `O(2n)` short-lived strings in Ruby, unless you use the frozen string literal pragma. Why? Each time the interpreter encounters a string literal it creates a copy of that literal.

Comment: Hardly worth mentioning, but (to avoid the creation of a temporary array) I suggest `each_char` when followed by an `Enumerable` method.

Comment: @CarySwoveland : Thanks. You're totally right. I was just benchmarking, and noticed that my method is 160x slower than mudasobwa's. :D

Comment: `chars` and `each_char` are the same method. It returns an enumerator.

Comment: @akuhn No they're not : http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-chars

Comment: The `$` command in `pry` yields the same source code for `rb_str_each_char` but maybe that has changed in Ruby 2.4?

Comment: It was an Enum in 1.9.x, it's been an Array since 2.0.x

Comment: `return rb_str_enumerate_chars(str, 0);` and `return rb_str_enumerate_chars(str, 1);`

Comment: Oh interesting! I see there is `rb_str_enumerate_chars(VALUE str, int wantarray)`

Comment: Proof that `String#chars` returns an array: `"hello".chars.join("-") #=> "h-e-l-l-o"`. @Eric, how would this have been written in v1.9? Surely not `"hello".chars.to_a.join("-")` (Ugh!)

Comment: Because it's been whupped with an ugly stick. Please add `str =~ /[[:alpha:]]/` to your benchmark.

Comment: Wow, interesting! Thanks for running this benchmark. What gem did you use for that?

Comment: You could probably speed up your code by using `each_codepoint` which avoids the creation of strings for each character. However that would really be premature optimization at the cost or readability.

Answer (score 2):

```
checker = lambda do |input|
  "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split('').any? &input.downcase.method(:include?)
end

checker.('3F3')
#⇒ true
checker.('42')
#⇒ false
```

Comment: Do you really need to call `downcase` 26 times? :

Comment: @EricDuminil it’s still better than calling `include?` 1M times on 1MB string, having a last letter :)

Comment: Does it really make a difference? I'd say that our methods have exactly the same complexity. We have a matrix of `include?`, you use the rows, I use the columns.

Comment: @EricDuminil indeed.