# How can I check if user input contains a letter?

Tags: regex, ruby, string

In Ruby, I want to see if user input contains any letter in the alphabet.

I have tried using `contains` and `include?`, but neither of these worked.

Comment: One way is to use a simple regular expression: `str.match?(/[A-Za-z]/)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Ruby, can I check if a string contains a letter without using regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536289/in-ruby-can-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-letter-without-using-regular-express)

Comment: @Kache The OP does not specify anything about regexes, unlike the question you linked to (which says: *I don't want to use regular expressions*)

Comment: @TimurShtatland technically true, but OP does not require that regexes to be used, and thus the answer to that question perfectly answers this one. A simple "ruby contains letter" search would have answered the question.

Comment: "not working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts! https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/ https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Answer (score 2):

See [String#include?](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/include%3F)

For example:

```
myString.include? 'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the comment from Cary: use a regular expression (regexp):

```
puts ‘matches’ if in_str =~ /[A-Za-z]/
```

See also: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Regexp.html